# Firebase keeps track of previous inserted records

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created a sample app linking firebase and HTML using simple javascript.

Even after clearing the whole database I couldn't make an entry with an email which I had been used previously

Does the firebase keep record of the previously inserted records?

## html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
    <h1 style="color:red">Welcome</h1>
    <button onclick="Login()">Login</button>
    <button onclick="create()">Create</button>
    <button onclick="getUserDetails()">user details</button>
    <button onclick="signOut()">Sign out</button>

    Email :
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
</body>

</html>
```

## javascript

```js
function load() {
    var config = {
<firebase config>
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

function Login() {
    var data = {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("pass").value
    };
                console.log(data)
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
        .then(function (authData) {
            console.log(authData)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);

        });
}
function create() {
    var data = {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("pass").value
    };
    console.log(data)
    firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
        .then(function (user) {
            writeUserData("123", "test", data.email, data.password)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("creation Failed!", error);

        });
}

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, pwd) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        username: name,
        email: email,
        test: pwd
    });
}
```

In the console, I get success message ie successful login and i get token in return from firebase even there is no data in the database.

When trying to create a new user with the same email id after clearing/deleting the data from console I get user already exists error

Please tell me the reason for this behavior.

## browser console

[image: Console of the app]

## Firebase console

[image: Firebase console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message comes from Firebase Authentication, which says that the email address is already in use by another account. You're deleting data from the Firebase Realtime Database. Firebase Authentication stores its user information in a separate location, and it has no knowledge of the JSON data that you're storing about those same users.

To find the account information that Firebase Authentication keeps for the user (and delete it), go to the [Authentication panel in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/users).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I had figured out the issue after a lot of debugging